# Python regex capture group issue

Tags: python, regex

Trying to specify my capture group, but it keeps capturing way too much.

Line:

```
"This is something of [Interest: stuff]. blah blah blah"
```

Regex:

```
patt = re.compile('\[Interest:(.){1,100}\]')
```

What is output:

```
[Interest: stuff]
```

What I want output:

```
stuff
```

How can I output just what I want to capture, and not the entire pattern?

I've also tried this:

```
re.compile(r'\[Interest:(?P<interest>.+)\]')
```

That outputs:

```
stuff]. blah blah blah
```

I feel like im pretty close. Just need to figure out how to stop the output once regex hits the ]

Comment: Side note, `\[Interest:(.{1,100}?)\]` or `\[Interest:([^\]]{1,100})\]` are probably better alternatives..I don't have any knowledge of accessing capture groups in Python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `.` character matches everything except for newlines, including `]`.  So, `(.){1,100}` is telling Python to get everything it can up to `100` characters long.  This includes the end of the string.

Instead, I would use this pattern:

```
\[Interest:\s([^\]]*)\]
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "This is something of [Interest: stuff]. blah blah blah"
>>> re.search("\[Interest:\s([^\]]*)\]", string).group(1)
'stuff'
>>>
```

Below is an explanation of what it matches:

```
\[         # [
Interest:  # Interest:
\s         # A space
(          # The start of a capture group
[^\]]*     # Zero or more characters that are not ]
)          # The close of the capture group
\]         # ]
```

For more information, see [Regular Expression Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

Comment: Err the 'most important' part is actually irrelevant if you use a negated class and is instead impeding the processing time of the regex. You should either use a lazy quantifier on a wildcard that matches everything, or a greedy quantifier on a negated class in such instances.

Comment: +1 for nice explanation @Sugitime you said it's perfect but it looks like you forgot to click the checkmark. :)

Comment: Yup your right. iCodez answered so fast, I had to wait 6 minutes to click the checkbox and I guess it slipped my mind. Thank you for the reminder, and thanks again iCodez for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Get the matched group from index 1 using lazy way.

```
\[Interest: (.*?)\]
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sR4oP7/1)

sample code:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'\[Interest: (.*?)\]', re.IGNORECASE)
test_str = u"This is something of [Interest: stuff]. blah blah blah"

re.match(p, test_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

one issue with you regex: `\[Interest:(.){1,100}\]` ,   is that `(.){1,100}` will **allow 1 to 100** of `.` BUT it'll **capture just one `.`**, the last `.`, because the `(` `)` are enclosing only `.` (which refers to a single char). therefore the *captured group* will contain the `f` of `stuff`.

instead, `\[Interest: (.{1,100})\]` will return `stuff`.

as for the output being `[Interest: stuff]`.. that is a grouping issue.
Try `iCodez`'s code [HERE](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_python_online.php):

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "This is something of [Interest: stuff]. blah blah blah"
>>> re.search("\[Interest:\s([^\]]*?)\]", string).group(1)
```

it prints `stuff`.

replace `.group(1)` with `.group(0)` and it prints `[Interest: stuff]`.